# java.lang.NullPointerException: can't get a shadow for null ShadowPreferenceManager

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito

Could someone help me understand how to fix this exception?

I referenced [Robolectric tests fail on shadowOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028933/robolectric-tests-fail-on-shadowof) but I'm already using `this` to access the `SharedPreferences` i.e.

`SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);`

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

    private Context context;
    private SomeClassTest someClassTest;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        context = mock(Context.class);
        sharedPreferences = ShadowPreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        someClassTest = new SomeClassTest(context);
    }

    @Test
    public void someClassProduction() {
        when(someClassTest.getEnvironment()).thenReturn("PRODUCTION");
        when(someClassTest.getBaseUrl()).thenReturn("https://www.someUrl.com/v1/");
        assertTrue(someclassTest.getTestUrl().equals("https://www.someurl.com/v1/counts.json")
    }
}
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: can't get a shadow for null
    at org.robolectric.bytecode.ShadowWrangler.shadowOf(ShadowWrangler.java:442)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.shadowOf_(Robolectric.java:1059)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.shadowOf(Robolectric.java:477)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowPreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ShadowPreferenceManager.java:21)
    at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java)
```

Comment: We are missing some important information: which reference is null ? Could you check the value of "context" before calling "getDefaultSharedPreferences(...)" to make sure that your "mock(...)" method works properly ?

Comment: Gotcha, @bdulac I debugged the failing test - context is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had to replace `context = mock(Context.class)` with `context = Robolectric.application`

Here's the updated test:

```
@Config(emulateSdk = 18)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SomeClassTest {

    private Context context;
    private SomeClassTest someClassTest;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        context = Roboelectric.application;
        sharedPreferences = ShadowPreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        someClassTest = new SomeClassTest(context);
    }

    @Test
    public void someClassProduction() {
        when(someClassTest.getEnvironment()).thenReturn("PRODUCTION");
        when(someClassTest.getBaseUrl()).thenReturn("https://www.someUrl.com/v1/");
        assertTrue(someclassTest.getTestUrl().equals("https://www.someurl.com/v1/counts.json")
    }
}
```